# WatchOS 2.2 Large Modular Complication Fails To Initally Display Image

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

I've discovered a new issue in WatchOS 2.2 large modular complication.  I have a work-around, but was wondering if anyone knows of a fix for this?

Install your WatchOS app that includes a large modular complication with an image.  Go to the Watch face configuration by hard pressing.  Choose the modular layout (second one to the right).  Customize to add your large modular complication to the center of the watch face.  Hit the home button twice to return to the Watch face.  Note that your image only shows as a shadow when holding down the complication.

Return to the Watch face configuration by hard pressing.  Change the text color of your watch face.  Hit the home button twice to return to the Watch face.  Note that your image now shows correctly.  You can now change the color back to the original color and the watch complication image will still show.

Anyone else seen this bug in WatchOS 2.2?  Anyone have a programatic fix instead of a user work-around as I describe above?

Thanks!

Justin

Comment: Hi, do you get any workaround for it?